# Issue using rfid reader to get a program to execute

Tags: rfid, os.system

Hi I'm trying to use a rfid card reader to send an instruction to the Lightshowpi program. I am pretty new to this but have managed to put some code together but I can't seem to get it to play a song.
The code is as follows:

```
import os
from time import sleep

tag = input ("\nPlease scan your tag\n")

while tag != "":

if tag == "1":
    print ("tag 1", tag)
    os.system('pkill -f "bash $SYNCHRONIZED_LIGHTS_HOME/bin"')
    os.system('pkill -f "python $SYNCHRONIZED_LIGHTS_HOME/py"')
    os.system("python ${SYNCHRONIZED_LIGHTS_HOME}/py/hardware_controller.py --state=off")
    tag=0

elif tag == "2":
    print ("tag 2", tag)        
    os.system('pkill -f "bash $SYNCHRONIZED_LIGHTS_HOME/bin"')
    os.system('pkill -f "python $SYNCHRONIZED_LIGHTS_HOME/py"')
    os.system("python ${SYNCHRONIZED_LIGHTS_HOME}/py/hardware_controller.py --state=on")
    tag=0

elif tag == "3":
    print ("tag 3", tag)
    os.system('pkill -f "bash $SYNCHRONIZED_LIGHTS_HOME/bin"')
    os.system('pkill -f "python $SYNCHRONIZED_LIGHTS_HOME/py"')
    os.system("python ${SYNCHRONIZED_LIGHTS_HOME}/py/synchronized_lights.py --file=/home/pi/lightshowpi/music/sample/ovenrake_deck-the-halls.mp3")
    tag=0

else:
   print ("incorrect bozo")

tag = input("Please scan your tag\n")
```

When I input either tag 1 or 2 I send the command to the program to switch on the lights. This works fine. But when I input tag 3 nothing happens apart from returning the tag number.

If i use the shell and input

```
import os
os.system("python ${SYNCHRONIZED_LIGHTS_HOME}/py/synchronized_lights.py --file=/home/pi/lightshowpi/music/sample/ovenrake_deck-the-halls.mp3")
```

it returns 256 which i believe is an access error. I don't understand how the first 2 work but the second one doesn't. 
Any help would be great and if i'm barking up the wrong tree any direction would be great and I imagine the code could be tidied up so any help there too would be great. Thanks.